# FFMPEG combine audio / video & add logo in one command

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, images, combine

Hi there i have a local server for video production i am trying to combine an audio and video clip using Ffmpeg i can combine the audio and video no problem but when i try to also add a logo over lay onto the video the commands dont seem to work i am no expert with ffmpeg in fact i have only ever used it for segmentation so this is all new to me.

i have tried using the following command

```
-i video.mp4 -i logo.png -i audio.aac -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25" -c:a copy -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Comment: *"dont seem to work"* Please show the complete log from the command, and explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop the logo.png file like

```
ffmpeg \
-i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i logo.png -i audio.aac \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x=25:y=25:shortest=1" \
-c:a copy -strict experimental output.mp4
```

otherwise it won't play for the entire duration of the video.